# test stream-rabbitmq occurs an error: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I code a test class for using spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit, when I only run receiver, and send a message from rabbitmq, it works; but when I run the test sender class, it occurs an error: `org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel`, what should I do to make it correct?

My step:

First, run SpringbootApplication
Second, run JUnit test

spring-boot-starter-parent 2.1.3.RELEASE
JDK8
rabbitmq
utf8

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springcloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>stream-hello</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>stream-hello</name>
    <description>SpringCloud Project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

SinkReceiver.java

```
@EnableBinding({Sink.class})
public class SinkReceiver {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SinkReceiver.class);

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void receive(Object payload) {
        logger.info("Received: " + payload);
    }

}
```

StreamHelloApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class StreamHelloApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StreamHelloApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

StreamHelloApplicationTests.java

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@EnableBinding(value = {StreamHelloApplicationTests.SinkSender.class})
public class StreamHelloApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private SinkSender sinkSender;

    @Test
    public void sinkSenderTester() {
        sinkSender.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("produce a message : sinkSenderTest").build());
    }

    public interface SinkSender {
        String OUTPUT = "input";

        @Output(SinkSender.OUTPUT)
        MessageChannel output();
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.application.name=stream-hello

#config rabbitmq
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=35672
spring.rabbitmq.username=admin
spring.rabbitmq.password=123456
```

I expect the junit test can run successful, but it run occurs error. stack trace like follow:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@68ceda24.input'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[34], headers={contentType=application/json, id=fc0a6890-4945-142b-55cd-668b0d3f22ed, timestamp=1555817595975}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[34], headers={contentType=application/json, id=fc0a6890-4945-142b-55cd-668b0d3f22ed, timestamp=1555817595975}]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:461)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:401)
    at com.springcloud.StreamHelloApplicationTests.sinkSenderTester(StreamHelloApplicationTests.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[34], headers={contentType=application/json, id=fc0a6890-4945-142b-55cd-668b0d3f22ed, timestamp=1555817595975}]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:138)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    ... 34 more
```

Comment: Through  adding @SpringbootTest on the class "StreamHelloApplicationTests ",  and then update ```String OUTPUT = "output";```, after doing these, add ``` spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=sink-data-topic ```,  ``` spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=sink-data-topic ``` in the properties file to direct the channel to the same topic can solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binding interface `SinkSender` is not bound to anything. The "input" channel is created but there is no subscriber. And your `SinkReceiver` is not even part of the test.
For testing please read the [Testing](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.2.0.RC1/spring-cloud-stream.html#_testing) of the user manual especially the new [test binder](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.2.0.RC1/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring_integration_test_binder). The above section contain full working samples as well.

Comment: it's strange, i test the code at the version 1.5.9, it works;  but does't work at 2.1.3. And thanks , i'll  take a look on it

Comment: Yes, there were some changes since 1.5.x. However, understand that sending message directly to channel you are only testing the functionality of your consumer completely bypassing all the bindings and the binder, and if that is what you want to do there are much simpler ways of testing it (e.g., a simple unit test which would invoke method directly). The new test binder that I was referring to earlier was specifically designed to ensure you are testing your functionality and it's interaction with spring-cloud-stream binding framework.